# Unity 5 Saving and Loading variables

Tags: save, load, unity-game-engine

i know i can save int,float,string with PlayerPrefs, but how can i save a boolean too, like the Player has money, and he is bought an upgrade, how can i save if the player bought the upgrade and load it next time?

I have my upgrades like this:

```
  public void Computer()
{
    if(tier1 == true && Click.money >= cost)
    {
        Click.money -= cost;
        ItemNameInfo.text = "[TIER II]Computer";
        UpgradeInfo.text = "Wooaah! Upgrade Time!\n(Gives +5 CPS)";
        cost = 1000;
        costInfo.text = "Cost: " + cost;
        Click.moneyperclick += 1;
        tier1 = false;
        tier2 = true;
    }
    else if(tier2 == true && Click.money >= cost)
    {
        Click.money -= cost;
        ItemNameInfo.text = "[TIER III]Computer";
        UpgradeInfo.text = "It's still isn't good enough\n(Gives +10 CPS)";
        cost = 20000;
        costInfo.text = "Cost: " + cost;
        Click.moneyperclick += 5;
        tier2 = false;
        tier3 = true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot save bools to Player Prefs.

I tend to just use an int.

For example, let's say we have an item "item1".

To check if the player has that item unlocked:

```
if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hasItem1",0) == 1){
    //player has item 1
}
```

to unlock item1:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hasItem1",1);
```

Comment: And how can i refer to that item simply just type in the class, that item1 = Scriptname.item1?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you are referring to?

Comment: The question was about saving bools to playerprefs. If you need advice on structuring your upgrade system, perhaps ask a separate question.

Comment: If i have these integers in an other script, is it enough to type in the serializable class that item1 = Scriptname.item1?

Comment: Where do i have to put the Checker? To check if the player has the item?